# Border of a selected tile in the start menu be more visible?

Tags: windows-8.1, modern-ui

I'm trying to customize my start screen in such a way that selection a tile will clearly mark the tile selected in the start screen. Amama, the highlight around selected tiles, regardless of which color plan I choose in the windows 8 personalization, is always a slightly brighter color then the background and is HARDLY NOTICABLE!

does anyone know how to specifically customize this color/ border width or anything helpful?

Comment: Does this issue still occur if you change your brightness/contrast settings on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

If you point your mouse over the tiles, the borders will be really dim. But if you select a tile by keyboard, the border color will be white. And you can notice it easily. Hope this may help. :)

Comment: I haven't noticed that before, thanks! I'm still trying to highlight the box that my mouse hovers over, so without knowing which box is where and how big it is, I can't move the keyboard to that box to enjoy that lovely white frame, but that is definitely helpful nonetheless.

Comment: Just use the arrow keys. It should highlight the tiles. :)